# Python3 | sqlite3: executemany() inserts nothing

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sql-insert, executemany

I am trying to use `sqlite3`'s `executemany()` to insert multiple values with `Python3`.

**Code:**

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('rssnewsdata.db')
c = conn.cursor()

entries = [
    ('url1', 1234, 'title1', 'summary1', 'feedurl1'),
    ('url2', 1235, 'title2', 'summary2', 'feedurl2'),
    ('url3', 1236, 'title3', 'summary3', 'feedurl3'),
    ('url4', 1237, 'title4', 'summary4', 'feedurl4')
]

c.executemany('INSERT INTO entries VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', entries)
```

The `db` file exists, the table exists, I can use `Python3` to `SELECT` from it, so connecting to it is not a problem. The columns are of `TEXT`, `INTEGER`, `TEXT`, `TEXT`, `TEXT` type.

`Python` reports no errors. What is missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to

```
conn.commit()
```

after the insert.